# Apache Solr Search Integtation and the Default Drupal Search Form

Tags: search, display-suite

Apache Solr Search Integtation (apachesolr module) is dependent on the core Search module. I set this up at https://www.test.epcsite.com/search/content. I also setup display suite so that I can theme my search results.

I have a couple questions:

1. The Default Search form uses Drupal core search. If you go to https://www.test.epcsite.com/search it redirects to https://www.test.epcsite.com/search/content, I don't quite know why. I would like it to stay on "/search".
2. apachesolor setup a url at /search/site, which puts a tab on the search form. Clicking on the tab takes you to another search form, but it won't use Display Suite to theme the results. The tab itself is confusing and it would be nice to get rid of it.
3. Going to https://www.test.epcsite.com/search/content displays "Your search yielded no results" but I haven't run the search yet. How do I customize this message not to show? How do I customize the message so that it says what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming Drupal 7.

1. This is a limitation of the way core Search is implemented in D7. Try the [Custom Search](https://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module; it can somehow change the way search paths are handled, although I have not used it.
2. One tab would be for core search, and the other for Apache Solr search. Go to `/admin/config/search/settings` and disable all search modules except Apache Solr, and also set it as default. Now the only available search path will be the one set up at `/admin/config/search/apachesolr/search-pages`.
3. I cannot replicate this on my Apache Solr & Drupal 7 setup. In general, to change strings that are hard coded into modules, use the [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.